# Flutter: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':geolocator:compileDebugAidl'

Tags: flutter

I'd added `geolocator` and I am getting

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':geolocator:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':geolocator:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:{strictly 2.0.0}.
     Required by:
         project :geolocator
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'com.baseflow.geolocator:geolocator:1.0' --> 'io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-df39e5c51517a73e61647286ab21252074512c63' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.2.0'
           Constraint path 'com.baseflow.geolocator:geolocator:1.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:{strictly 2.0.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
           Dependency path 'com.baseflow.geolocator:geolocator:1.0' --> 'io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-df39e5c51517a73e61647286ab21252074512c63' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.2.0'
           Dependency path 'com.baseflow.geolocator:geolocator:1.0' --> 'io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-df39e5c51517a73e61647286ab21252074512c63' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.2.0'
           Dependency path 'com.baseflow.geolocator:geolocator:1.0' --> 'io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-df39e5c51517a73e61647286ab21252074512c63' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0' --> 'androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0'
           Dependency path 'com.baseflow.geolocator:geolocator:1.0' --> 'io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-df39e5c51517a73e61647286ab21252074512c63' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0' --> 'androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0'
```

such error.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.helloworld.android"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

gradle.properties
    org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
    android.useAndroidX=true
    android.enableJetifier=true
    android.enableR8=true
```

AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.helloworld">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

How can I resolve this? geolocator works totally fine on iOS. I bet I have done something wrong in the setting. But, I can not quite sure what it is.

```
** pubspec
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  get: ^3.22.2
  custom_splash: ^0.0.2
  http: ^0.12.2
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
  google_fonts: ^1.1.1
  flutter_slidable: ^0.5.7
  get_storage: ^1.3.2
  background_fetch: ^0.6.0
  video_player: ^1.0.1
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^1.0.0+1
  socket_io_client: ^0.9.12
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.6
  url_launcher: ^5.7.10
  animations: ^1.1.2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  sign_in_with_apple: ^2.5.4
  connectivity: ^2.0.2
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+14
  google_maps_flutter: ^1.0.6
  package_info: ^0.4.3+2
  share: ^0.6.5+4
  camera: ^0.5.8+17
  sensors: ^0.4.2+6
  battery: ^1.0.7
  splash_screen_view: ^1.0.3
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  fab_circular_menu: ^1.0.0
  liquid_pull_to_refresh: ^2.0.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.10.1
  cached_network_image: ^2.4.1
  geolocator: ^6.1.13
  flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle: ^1.0.11

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/videos/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: auth_font
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/auth_font.ttf
        

  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: try this command.  $ flutter pub cache repair

Comment: I just tried but no luck.

Comment: add pubspec code

Comment: ok! this is fine.. can you just remove ^ from geolocator and again sync

Comment: Same errors! :/

Comment: You need to migrate to androidX. https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/275#issuecomment-497833432

Comment: Oh dang. I just had to upgrade my flutter project! Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i have read the full error log and i was figuring out what the issue is..

`io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug` library got updated and now requires version 2.2.0 of the `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime` library while the geolocator can only supply version 2.0.0.

issue
[#624](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/624)

Comment: I upgraded and then google_sign_in and other packages get broken. how can I use 2.0.0 without upgrading?!

Answer (score 2):

This fixed the problem for me:

1. update the `com.android.tools.build:gradle` dependency version in `./android/build.gradle` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'`
2. Change `distributionUrl` in `./android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip`